# how to set slider in both side android

Tags: android, slider

I am trying to make sliding drawer menu like the one in the YouTube app. I navigated many questions like this amazing one here. and found a lot of libraries but all of them slide from left to right or from right to left in different one. I want to make it slide from both sides, left to right and right to left via two buttons in the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer, which mekes it possible for you to slide from any side.

Comment: "thanks for the reply, i have implement this code issue is solve"

Answer (score 0):

Use Yahoo Rangeseekbar

The package is

```
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar
```

It will let you slide both the sides and you can choose if you want to display the values on the top of the slider min and max ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) from the support library. As it says in the documentation, you can control the placement of the drawers with the `layout_gravity` attribute. From the documentation:

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first child with a width and height of `match_parent`. Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the `layout_gravity` appropriately. Drawers commonly use `match_parent` for height with a fixed width.